# How should I use the method of Lagrange multipliers to show that the area is maximized when the triangle is equilateral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Heron's formula for the area A of a triangle with sides of length $a, b, c>0$ is $A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$, where $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. Use the method of Lagrange multipliers to show that for a given fixed perimeter $p=2s$ of the triangle, the area is maximized when the triangle is equilateral.

I set up the function with $A(a, b, c)=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ but what should be the constraint here and how to apply the method of Lagrange multipliers to do this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can consider maximizing the area of the squared function instead since this will preserve order. This will avoid dealing with the square root function in the partial derivatives
$$\begin{aligned}f(a,b,c) = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c) &= \frac{1}{16}(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)\\
&=\frac{1}{16} [-a^4+2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2-b^4+2b^2c^2-c^4]
\end{aligned}$$

And let our constraint function simply be $g(a,b,c) = 2s = a+b+c$.

We want to determine $(a,b,c)$ where $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$, so we evaluate the partials to get the gradients. Then, we write the relationship for Lagrange multipliers with these:
$$\frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}-a^3+ab^2+ac^2 \\ a^2b-b^3+bc^2\\a^2c+b^2c-c^3\end{bmatrix} = \lambda\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

In the case where these three expressions on the left-hand side are equal to each other and $a,b,c$ are all positive, the only solution is where $a=b=c$, that is where the triangle is equilateral.

To elaborate slightly on why the sides must be equal, notice that for
$$a(-a^2+b^2+c^2) - b(-b^2+a^2+c^2) =0 \implies (b-a)(a+b-c)(a+b+c) =0$$
and you have similar expressions for the other pairs.

Edit:
I am showing the algebra steps. I just apply difference of squares over and over.
$$\begin{aligned}
&(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)\\ &= ((a+b)+c)((a+b)-c)(c-(a-b))(c+(a-b))\\
&=((a+b)^2-c^2)(c^2-(a-b)^2)\\
&= (a+b)^2c^2 -(a+b)^2(a-b)^2 -c^4 +c^2(a-b)^2\\
&= c^2((a+b)^2+(a-b)^2) -(a+b)^2(a-b)^2 -c^4 \\
&=c^2(2a^2+2b^2)-(a+b)^2(a-b)^2 -c^4\\
&=c^2(2a^2+2b^2)-(a^2-b^2)^2 -c^4\\
&=-a^4+2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2-b^4+2b^2c^2-c^4
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Since $s$ is fixed, you can simplify the function to maximize to $(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$

Comment: As a minor point, you need to show that a $\max$ exists first.  With the relaxed constraints $a,b,c \ge 0$, the domain is compact hence a $\max$ exists. $a=b=c = {p \over 3}$ shows that the $\max$ is non zero and at the $\max$ all the $a,b,c$ are non zero.

Comment: But how to get $\frac{1}{8}(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)=\frac{1}{8}[-a^4+2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2-b^4+2b^2c^2-c^4]$?

Comment: @Purity I have added the algebra in an edit for you

Comment: How about the $\frac{1}{8}$ in the front?

Comment: @Purity It should be $\frac{1}{16}$ instead. It comes from the semiperimeter and the difference terms. But the coefficient in this case does not matter for seeing the conclusion

Comment: So in conclusion, we can state that $a=b=c$, right?

Comment: Yes, based on the Lagrange multiplier equations

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @RichardKYu May you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4847392/how-should-i-show-that-there-is-only-one-stationary-path-for-this-given-function ? I need help on this problem.